# Bridge rectifier - min. required protective resistor

Tags: resistors, datasheet, circuit-protection, bridge-rectifier

Looking at the [datasheet](http://www.ret.hu/DataSheets/95_SMD_DIOD%C3%81K,GR%C3%89CEK/DIO_011/mys40.pdf) for a MYS80 bridge rectifier, at the bottom it states **Min. required protective resistor** is 8 ohm. I could not find much information about a protective resistor in regard to bridge rectifier on the internet. Can anyone elaborate?

[image: MYS80 protective resistor]

Comment: I am quite confident it is the minimum resistive load you can apply to the bridge rectifier, or else the chip burns. I assume that it is specified at 380V but the datasheet isn't too clear about it.

Comment: @lucas92: I am quite confident that you are incorrect. 8 Ω on 380 V would pull > 40 A. The device is rated at 0.5 A. In any case, the minimum resistance would depend on the voltage of the circuit. As the datasheet suggests it's related to the capacitance and the surge that will create on power-up.

Comment: @Transistor : 380V refers to a different diode in the same datasheet, for which  R=40 ohms.

Comment: Confidence slightly dented. ;^) The 8 Ω is for the MYS80 (80 V) and the 40 Ω is for the MSY380 (380 V) so they're limiting the current to 10 A peak. The question has made me look up the details. I'll post an answer later. Thanks.

Comment: You can actually put a VGS (mos transistor) so the canal of the transistor is not completely opened (it won't be seen as a 8 ohms resistor).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main purpose of a protective resistor would be to limit the inrush current presented by a discharged capacitive load to the peak AC voltage the particular bridge can tolerate. This could be a fixed resistor or a task-specific negative temperature coefficient thermistor connected in series with the load.

You see these all the time in switching power supplies - quite often the resistor/thermistor will get bypassed by a relay or triac once the capacitors have charged up to the peak of the line to improve efficiency and prevent the element from burning power all the time.

(The resistor values compute to approximately 10A for the datasheet you specified - for a small bridge, my gut says this is reasonable.)

Comment: Thank You for the answer. How did you calculate that 14A figure, please?

Comment: Actually "Repetitive peak reverse voltage" / "Peak forward surge current" = 160/20 = 8 ohms. Coincidence?

Comment: @delmadord Typo/boo-boo fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Good question. I had never come across the term "min. required protective resistor" before although I am familiar with the problem.

Diotec Semiconductor have a good two-page application note, [Bridge Rectifier Fundamentals](http://diotec.com/tl_files/diotec/files/pdf/service/applications/bridge-rectifier.pdf) or Why to use Diotec Products for Input Rectification. In section D they say:

> **Inrush Current Limitation, \$R_t , C_L , I_{FSM}\$
>
> A description of this
>   parameters can be found in Diotec's  [technical information](http://diotec.com/tl_files/diotec/files/pdf/products/generalinformation/technik.pdf),  as
>   well as in the data sheet of the  [MiniDIL](http://diotec.com/tl_files/diotec/files/pdf/datasheets/s40.pdf) series. Inrush happens only
>   at capacitive load, so only in this case a limitation is required. It
>   is a good practice to limit the maximum inrush current to about 50% of
>   the rated I FSM  value. Often an NTC (thermistor) is used as a simple
>   solution to limit the inrush current. If however during operation (NTC
>   low resistive) the mains drops and comes back, there is the risk of
>   excessive inrush current.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKz1pE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Inrush limiting.*

Many variable speed drives, etc., use an inrush limiting resistor in series with the supply to limit the current into the capacitor as this presents a short-circuit on power-on. The Diotec data sheet shows one or more between the supply and the rectifier. Placing it after the rectifier means only one is required. A voltage sensing circuit will close SW1 when the capacitor voltage gets to some preset level - 50 to 80%, I expect.

The MYSxx series appear to have a 10 A surge limit so that determines the series resistance required for a particular voltage. Obviously, if using the higher voltage type on, for example, an 80 V circuit then the 8 Ω series resistance would be required.

Comment: Thank you for the link from Diotec, really did not know about it.